# Retrieve Excel application from process id

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I am starting an Excel application using the `Process` class. I am able to get the process id & the main window handle with the code below.

```
  Process xlP = Process.Start("excel.exe");
  int id = xlP.Id;
  int hwnd = (int)Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
```

So this starts an Excel application. How do I reference this particular instance of Excel with the process id & main window handle?

I have seen similar questions on here but the answer was a link to a webpage that no longer exists.

I basically want something like below.

```
oExcelApp =  (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

Please not the Excel application has to be started using the `Process.Start` method, no if buts or maybes.

Comment: What is wrong with GetActiveObject after Process.Start? By default there will only be one instance of Excel running. If there are multiple instances you would need to walk the ROT table, get each instance and lookup the processid from App.HWND

Comment: @AlexK. thanks for the reply. We are using windows 7 and it is possible for there to be more than one instance of excel open at any time. Thats why I thought the process id would be helpful however think I'm wrong. Sorry whats the ROT table? can tell this is new to me

Comment: Just curious, what are you trying to do with the open excel doc?

Comment: basically when I open a excel application I need an add-inn (Bloomberg) to be present - the only way I can seem to get the bloomberg add-in is by using the Process.Start method. I then need to call some bloomberg functions to check some data. I would normally use the bloomberg api however the data is not available through the api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to access all running Excel instances and display the Window Handle they use:

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable prot);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IRunningObjectTable lRunningObjectTable = null;
    IEnumMoniker lMonikerList = null;

    try
    {
        // Query Running Object Table 
        if (GetRunningObjectTable(0, out lRunningObjectTable) != 0 || lRunningObjectTable == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // List Monikers
        lRunningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out lMonikerList);

        // Start Enumeration
        lMonikerList.Reset();

        // Array used for enumerating Monikers
        IMoniker[] lMonikerContainer = new IMoniker[1];

        IntPtr lPointerFetchedMonikers = IntPtr.Zero;

        // foreach Moniker
        while (lMonikerList.Next(1, lMonikerContainer, lPointerFetchedMonikers) == 0)
        {
            object lComObject;
            lRunningObjectTable.GetObject(lMonikerContainer[0], out lComObject);

            // Check the object is an Excel workbook
            if (lComObject is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook lExcelWorkbook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)lComObject;
                // Show the Window Handle 
                MessageBox.Show("Found Excel Application with Window Handle " + lExcelWorkbook.Application.Hwnd);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release ressources
        if (lRunningObjectTable != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(lRunningObjectTable);
        if (lMonikerList != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(lMonikerList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and use the following code:

```
        Process xlP = Process.Start("excel.exe");
        int id = xlP.Id;
        int hwnd = (int)Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

        Excel.Application oExcelApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

        if(xlP.MainWindowTitle.Contains( oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name)   )
        {
            //Proceed further
        }
```

Comment: works only if you're lucky to call GetActiveObject and get the instance you need and not some other one